# need help with sql server 2008 query - max from select

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this query and i need to get the max value of number and the city

how to do it ?

```
select city,count(id) as number
from men
group by city
order by number desc
```

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems ok.

Just add top 1 to get only first result:

```
select top 1 city,count(id) as number
from men
group by city
order by number desc
```

Comment: thank's for the help, but if i want the min value ? how to do it ?
(i think that need to use MAX or MIN in the query...???)

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Add a [`TOP` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to restrict the number of returned rows to 1. Note that parentheses for the top clause are optional in `select` statements where the number of rows is a constant. If you use anything other than a constant, you'll need parentheses and SQL Server 2005+. However, a `top` clause with constant number of rows without parentheses works on 2000 too.

```
select top 1 city,count(id) as number
from men
group by city
order by number desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top(1) city,count(id) as number
from men
group by city
order by number desc
```